# How do I ask a question in a sentence while referencing a quote?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, quotes

I am working on an assignment where you are supposed to ask Obama a question. I wanted to include the quote in the middle of my sentence and use that quote to help me ask my end question. I added a comma after the quote then asked my question. Is this correct (see below)?

> I assume you consider yourself now retired. After you and Michelle “...slept late, ate leisurely dinners, went for long walks, swam in the ocean, took stock, replenished our friendship, rediscovered our love, and planned for a less eventful but hopefully no less satisfying second act.”, Did you struggle to find a purpose excluding the standard post-presidency obligations?

Comment: Your sentence is very long, but I'd punctuate it: " ... second act,” did you ...

Comment: << I assume you consider yourself now retired. After you and Michelle [to quote] “_slept late, ate leisurely dinners, went for long walks, swam in the ocean, took stock, replenished [y]our friendship, rediscovered [y]our love, and planned for a less eventful but hopefully no less satisfying second act_”, did you struggle to find a purpose excluding the standard post-presidency obligations? >> But this doesn't remedy the style.

Answer (score 1):

DjinTonic is right that the best approach is probably to rework the sentence, but to directly address questions of punctuation and capitalization: If your sentence continues after the quoted material, you would replace the period with a comma (style conventions and manuals vary on whether it goes inside or outside the closing quote marks), and would *not* capitalize your next word.

Part of the point is that you're bending the original structure of the quoted sentence to fit the structure of the sentence you're crafting. As long as you don't misrepresent the quote, you want to fit it into your context, so even though "act" was the end of Obama's sentence, it's not the end of yours.

Comment: It might reflect region-specific norms, but I’d rather stop the quote before the full stop and put the comma outside the quote.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not sure whether it's regional, but it is a matter of style and thus not universal. I should edit to say so. I imagine I'm thinking getting this idea from Chicago...

Comment: @Andy Bonner I've never seen any style manual (including CMS) in the U.S. recommend other than what you stated in your answer. In UK English, the comma would go outside the quote mark (an incomplete sentence), but if it were a full stop, the quote mark would go after the stop, meeting the U.S. in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the "retired" assumption part of the question and put the quote at the end, for example:

> Do you consider yourself retired, and aside from post-presidency
> obligations, did you struggle to find a purpose after you and Michelle
> "...slept late, ate leisurely dinners, went for long walks, swam in the ocean, took stock, replenished our friendship, rediscovered our love, and planned for a less eventful but hopefully no less satisfying second act”?